# How can i read a single element from a Json object in react?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, express

I receive a JSON object from my express backend on my react application, but I don't know how to access one of its properties. I need the read the username field.

Since I have saved the JSON object on my react state, I have tried `this.state.datos.username` (returns `undefined`) and `this.state.datos[0].username` (returns a "cannot read property of undefined" error). I have checked some answers on this topic but maybe I'm kinda. clumsy and I can't manage to make this work.

This is my get method from express, sends the data of a user in JSON format.

```
app.get("/datosusuario", function(req, res, next) {
  res.json([
    {
      username: username,
      name: name,
      surname: surname,
      telephone: telephone,
      mail: mail,
      fax: fax
    }
  ]);
});
```

When checking in the browser, it shows this object:

[{"username":"Unknown","name":"This person","surname":"does not exist","telephone":"123123123","mail":"randomemail@gmail.com","fax":"584758924375892345"}]

Also, here is my `constructor` and my `componentDidMount` method:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      datos: []
    };
  }

componentDidMount(){
  fetch('/datosusuario')
  .then(userdata => userdata.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({ datos:data })
    console.log(this.state.datos);
  })
}
```

`console.log(this.state.datos)` and `console.log(data)` show the same:

```
[{…}]
0: {username: "Unknown", name: "This person", surname: "does not exist", telephone: "123123123", mail: "randomemail@gmail.com", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Chrome's React extension shows the same too.

I need to show a `Welcome{username}` message in my navigation bar component, which is looking like this (I'm using bootstrap):

```
        <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark">
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">Tecnolab</Navbar.Brand>

          <Nav className="justify-content-end">
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link href="/login">No está autenticado</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link href="/login">Login</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link href="/login">
                Welcome {this.state.datos.username}
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
```

Comment: modify res.json to `res.json({username: username,name: name,surname: surname,telephone: telephone,mail: mail,fax: fax});`

Comment: what error it is throwing?

Comment: Oh, changing res.json as you said fixed the error. (forgot to say, the error was cannot read property of undefined).

So, the problem is solved, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`this.state.datos` is **array** of objects as per console output, so you should fetch username as `this.state.datos[0].username`.

Comment: I mentioned in my post that this.state.datos[0].username returns an error. forgot to say it was that i cannot read a property of undefined. However, the problem is now solved by removing the [] in res.json

Answer (score 0):

update res.json to :

```
res.json({
  username: username,
  name: name,
  surname: surname,
  telephone: telephone,
  mail: mail,
  fax: fax
});
```